# What happened to Kirakishou in chapter 66 of Rozen Maiden Tales?

Tags: rozen-maiden

[image]

[image]

I just finished reading Tales (the second Rozen Maiden series), and I have a few questions.

- Did Jun from unwound world became Kirakishou's master? How was she awakened? Is it because the wound world Jun appeared?
- Regarding the dialogue on 24th page "How do you do, Master? We meet again. And just for a while, I'll be going.", does it mean that she will return to adult Jun shortly after helping his childish form with the creation of the new rose, **or** that she will be staying in awakened form only during their adventure to recreate Shinku? If it is the latter, does it mean that she will fall asleep again, as they succeed in their journey and she will be returned to the unwound Jun, **or** she will still stay awaken, after being waken up once?

Comment: I tried to clean up your question, but there were a few things I didn't understand so please check that I didn't mess anything up. Regarding manga reader sites, we don't allow questions here on such sites unless they are legally licensed to distribute the manga, which most aren't.

Comment: Yes, its okay, thx

Comment: Looks like nobdy knows...